# Fastest way to create this number?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a function to extend a number with sign to a wider bit length. This is a very frequently used action in the PowerPC instruction set. This is what I have so far:

```
function exts(value, from, to) {
    return (value | something_goes_here);
}
```

`value` is the integer input, `from` is the number of bits that the `value` is using, and `to` is the target bit length.

What is the most efficient way to create a number that has `to - from` bits set to `1`, followed by `from` bits set to `0`?

Ignoring the fact that JavaScript has no `0b` number syntax, for example, if I called

```
exts(0b1010101010, 10, 14)
```

I would want the function to OR the value with `0b11110000000000`, returning a sign-extended result of `0b11111010101010`.

Comment: JS doesn't have an integer type, only floating point numbers. You may wish to use typed arrays, but that will require modern browsers. Anyway, in C normally you'd do that by doing `(value|((-1)<<number_of_trailing_zeros))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A number containing `p` one bits followed by `q` zero bits can be generated via

```
((1<<p)-1)<<q
```

thus in your case

```
((1<<(to-from))-1)<<from
```

or much shorter

```
(1<<to)-(1<<from)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not overly familiar with binary mathematics in JavaScript... But if you need to OR a number with `0b11110000000000`, then I assume you would just convert that to decimal (which would get you `15360`), and do `value | 15360`.

Relevant info that you may find useful: `parseInt("11110000000000", 2)` converts a binary number (specified *as a string*) to a decimal number, and `(15360).toString(2)` converts a decimal number (15360 in this case) to a binary number (*the result is a string*).

---

**Revised solution**

There's probably a more elegant and mathematical method, but here's a quick-and-dirty solution:

```
var S = "";
for(var i=0;i<p;i++)
   S += "1";
for(i=0;i<q;i++)
   S += "0";
S = parseInt(S, 2); // convert to decimal
```

Comment: That was only an example. I'd like to know how to efficiently create a number that consists of `p` bits set to `1`, followed by `q` bits set to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the number 2^q (= 1 shifted left by q) represented as an integer of width p + q bits, it has the representation:

```
0...010...0
 p-1    q
```

then 2^q - 1 has the representation

```
0...01...1
  p    q
```

which is exactly the opposite of you want. So just flip the bits

hence what you want is NOT((1 LEFT SHIFT by q) - 1)
= `~((1 << q) - 1)` in c notation

Comment: But if I'm extending the number to something less than 32 bits, which is the only available 'integer-like' width in JavaScript (i.e., `(p + q) < 32`) then as far as I can tell, your method will cause the highest `32 - (p + q)` bits to be set to `1`, which is erroneous.

Comment: i was assuming you were using a type of the right width. you could AND what I had there with ((1 << to) - 1) to unset the higher bits

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks!